# Upgrade joomla site 1.7 to joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla1.7

**How to upgrade a version of joomla web site from 1.7 to joomla 2.5**

Comment: Have you googled your question? What have you tried? This is a common question for Joomla

Comment: http://docs.joomla.org/Upgrading_from_Joomla_1.7_to_Joomla_2.5

Comment: you should really use Google frst to find out something as simple as this ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can upgrade your site through extension manager. From Joomla 1.6 ,it has build-in update functionality in extension manager. For more detail see this tutorial :

[Upgrading from Joomla 1.7 to Joomla 2.5](http://docs.joomla.org/Upgrading_from_Joomla_1.7_to_Joomla_2.5)